# Retrieved "total_count":514 from FB, only want to post "514" to Parse

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, xcode6

`Result Dict: {
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 514;
    };
}`

Did a little research and my question was all wrong but the guy below led me to the right place. Was trying to get 514 from that NSDictionary and I got the answer [Getting information from a NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363762/getting-information-from-a-nsdictionary) there.

var totalCount: AnyObject? = yourDict.objectForKey("summary")!.objectForKey("total_count")!

that was the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save:

```
resultdict[0].summary.total_count
```

Comment: resultdict = "[{"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":514}}]", so when i save resultdict to parse it saves that whole line, i only want to save the "514".

Comment: Then just save `resultdict[0].summary.total_count` and if it works, let us know by accepting and/or upvoting the answer. If not, just shoot back another question.

Comment: Also, please "accept" the answer if it worked for you. You can "accept" the answer by clicking the green check mark that appears underneath the upvote arrows. That will let others know that follow that the answer worked for you.

Comment: sorry im really new. ths NSDictionary resultdict came back like this: Result Dict: {
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 514;
    };
}, ill edit my original post on top so u can see it better

Comment: ill choose ur answer just cuz u were the only one to respond. i figured it out but interacting with u led me to the right place