# Getting information from a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, nsdictionary

I named the result `resultdict` and the `NSDictionary` looks like this:

```
{
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 514;
    };
}
```

How do I get the "514" from that? I am using swift.

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the `514` from JSON to Swift?

Comment: no my project is using swift and i pulled a NSDictionary and that came as a result and i want to post the 514 to parse. so if i println(resultdict) that is the response.

Comment: You have a dictionary inside a dictionary.  Extract the inner dictionary from the outer, then extract the number from the inner dictionary.  Resist the temptation to do it all in one long line (as depicted by the answers below) as that is much harder to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it like :

```
var totalCount = yourDict.objectForKey("summary").objectForKey("total_count")
```

convert it to string

```
var totalCount = yourDict.objectForKey("summary").objectForKey("total_count") as! String
```

If you use :

```
println(totalCount)
```

will result in

```
Optional(514)
```

Use that variable as you want

Comment: the first one worked but it comes back with Optional(514) is there any way to only have 514

Comment: @gooberboobbutt you are trying to println then it will show Optional()

Comment: yes i am putting the first one into println, if i just post it to parse will optional not be there? trying it now will respond thanks! i spent 5 hours trying to figure it out and u answered back in like a minute

Comment: it posts as [514] how do i make it only 514, preferably as a int or string

Comment: intValue doesn't return an Int. It returns an Int32. You need to use integerValue

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
 var totalCount = yourDict.valueForKeyPath("summary.total_count")
```